# New Git branch option in Android Studio disabled

Tags: git, android-studio

I've been working on an Android Studio project for some time and now want to put it onto a local Git repository. There is no need for a remote repository - I am the only one working on it.

Somehow, after I've added all files to Git from VCS -> Add, I can't get to activate the New Branch option. Anyone else ever seen this issue? Is there a way I can check what is wrong with my project so that I can get all Git functionalities working?

Answer (score 5):

It is because you don't commit changes in files. After commit changes +new branch option being enable.

Comment: Why would you have to commit anything in order to create a new branch?

Comment: You can choose what files you want to commit their changes. For this purpose I create a text file in the root of my project and list files.

Comment: *.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures

Answer (score 3):

This happened when I had staged changes but no commits yet (though I thought I had made one).

Once I made a commit through command line the option to create a branch was available.

If you try branching without any commits using the command line, the master branch is gone.  Maybe that's why the option is disabled like this.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me also. The branches was not showing in android studio, but with command line was working ok. What I did was simply to register in the settings.

In Android Studio go to:

File>Other settings>default settings>Version control>Git

then you just click in 'add' button, and 'apply' changes.